# How to get the keys of the hashmap that have less than x value into an arraylist to make it regen to x value everytime the keys get less than x value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, bukkit

I'm making a Bukkit plugin where players have mana and spells. Each spell has it's own mana cost, and players start with 20 mana.

I have an `ArrayList` where I store the players that have less than 20 mana, and a `HashMap` that stores the players' current mana. I need to know how to make a method where it will add 1 mana every second to the players' with less than 20 mana.

I need to do this every time a player gets in the `ArrayList`, and then remove them from the list once they reach 20 mana.

Here is my current code:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> mana = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public ArrayList<String> changedMana = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onManaChange(){
  //code goes here
}
```

Comment: can you explain your question simply. I think these `mana` & `spells` wording making the question bit complicated.

Comment: well, there are spells that cost mana, mana is needed to cast spells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a task timer every second (this should be put in your `onEnable()` method):

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable(){
    public void run(){

    }
},20L,20L); //run this task every 20 ticks (20 ticks = 1 second)
```

and add mana to players that are in the `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String player : changedMana){ //loop through all of the players in the ArrayList
   int current = mana.get(player); //get the player's current mana
   if(current < 20){ //if the player's mana is less than 20
       current++; //add to the player's mana
       mana.put(player, current); //update the player's mana
   }
   else if(current == 20){ //if the player's mana is greater than or equal to 20
       toRemove.add(player); //add the player to the toRemove list, in order to remove the player from the ArrayList later safely
   }
   else{
     //do something if the current mana is > 20, if you don't want to, just remove this
   }
}

changedMana.removeAll(toRemove); //remove players from the changed mana array
```

So, here's what your code could look like if it were in your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`):

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> mana = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public ArrayList<String> changedMana = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onEnable(){
  Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(String player : changedMana){ //loop through all of the players in the ArrayList
        int current = mana.get(player); //get the player's current mana
        if(current < 20){ //if the player's mana is less than 20
           current++; //add to the player's mana
           mana.put(player, current); //update the player's mana
        }
        else if(current == 20){ //if the player's mana is greater than or equal to 20
           toRemove.add(player); //add the player to the toRemove list, in order to remove the player from the ArrayList later safely
        }
        else{
           //do something if the current mana is > 20, if you don't want to, just remove this
        }
      }

      changedMana.removeAll(toRemove); //remove players from the changed mana array
    }
  },20L,20L);
}
```

Comment: "Iterator.remove" is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Comment: The `if (current >= 20)` check is abundant because the only possible fall through from `if (current < 20) else` already matches the condition. The code is also suboptimal because a new `List` is constructed to handle a second loop to remove from the original `List`, where as `removeAll` would had done just fine — Though the optimal way is to just use an `Iterator` and use `else iterator.remove()`, which saves from the object construction and is easily more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to a `TreeMap` and use the [`headMap()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#headMap(K)).

Comment: Why?what's the difference ?

Comment: The TreeMap has guaranteed order, whereas a HashMap doesn't

Comment: @L3n Because `Treemap` has the `headMap()` method and `HashMap` doesn't.